Why can't node find the module?
I'm trying to add a currency to my bot and when I do node dbinit.js, it gives me module not found.
This is my script and the error that it gives me:
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    logging: false,
    storage: 'database.sqlite',
});

const CurrencyShop = require('models/currencyshop.js')(sequelize, DataTypes);
require('Mr.House/models/Users.js')(sequelize, DataTypes);
require('Mr.House/models/UserItems.js')(sequelize, DataTypes);

const force = process.argv.includes('--force') || process.argv.includes('-f');

sequelize.sync({ force }).then(async () => {
    const shop = [
        CurrencyShop.upsert({ name: 'Tea', cost: 1 }),
        CurrencyShop.upsert({ name: 'Coffee', cost: 2 }),
        CurrencyShop.upsert({ name: 'Cake', cost: 5 }),
    ];

    await Promise.all(shop);
    console.log('Database synced');

    sequelize.close();
}).catch(console.error);


Error: Cannot find module 'models/currencyshop.js'

I tried adding the main folder name, but nothing seems to work.

Your paths should start with ./ or ../ unless they're in the node_modules directory.

well i tried ./ and it didnt work and what do you meant by directory. (im a new at proggraming bots ;/) edit it worked but there is a new problem..... bruh

What kind of javascript framework do use? Angular, Vue , React or whatever. The use of "require" indicates that is not client side javascript.

Hi ! I added the node.js tag, might reach more node experts this way.

You're missing ./ in your require.
Third-party modules that you bring in via npm (e.g. npm install sequelize) can be specified (to require) using just the name of the module.  e.g. require('sequelize').
But your own JavaScript that files that exist in your source directory need to be specified with a relative path, prefixed with ./.
e.g.: require('./models/currencyshop.js')
Read the docs
The documentation for require says:

Modules can be imported from node_modules. Local modules and JSON files can be imported using a relative path (e.g. ./, ./foo, ./bar/baz, ../foo) that will be resolved against the directory named by __dirname (if defined) or the current working directory.

The use of ./ is how it disambiguates using third-party source files that npm installed into your node_modules folder (e.g.: require('debug') debug is a famous npm package available on npm) vs using a file in your source directory (e.g.: require('./debug') could be used to specify a file called debug.js in your current working directory.)

Assuming this is a local file in your project and not another module under node_modules, you need to prefix the path with ./:
const CurrencyShop = require('./models/currencyshop.js')(sequelize,DataTypes);
// Here ----------------------^

